# How do you perform a takedown?

Tags: payday-3

The skill "CQC Specialist" mentions performing takedowns to gain rush, and the remainder of that line is also mostly about takedowns. How do you perform a takedown to activate these skills?

[image: CQC Specialist - Basic: Whenever you perform a takedown, gain or refresh rush. Ace: Whenever you grab a human shield, gain or refresh grit.]

Comment: FYI, there are 3 additional tutorials after the one they force you to do when first booting up the game accessible from the main menu. These are actually pretty good and teach you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Takedown is a contextual prompt after taking a guard as a human shield. To take a guard down, take them as a human shield with your interact key, then press and hold that same key as prompted on screen.